# Wired connection not working Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet

My wired connection was working fine when all of a sudden, I got disconnected and wired connection stopped working. Wireless is still working and ethernet is working on Windows. Also, I am able to connect to the net when I use an external ethernet port through USB.

Some outputs that might be useful

`ifconfig`

```
enp1s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:36:99:a7  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:39419 (39.4 KB)  TX bytes:1151 (1.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:12935 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12935 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:658351 (658.3 KB)  TX bytes:658351 (658.3 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:b5:7d:05:ba:5e  
      inet addr:10.42.0.121  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::32bc:b5ab:5dc:9f7f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5848 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:6480
      TX packets:5007 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4093939 (4.0 MB)  TX bytes:824997 (824.9 KB)
      Interrupt:19
```

`lspci | grep -i net`

```
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

`sudo lshw -class network`

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
   logical name: enp1s0f1
   version: 12
   serial: f0:76:1c:36:99:a7
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:46 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b3504000-b3504fff memory:b3500000-b3503fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: ac:b5:7d:05:ba:5e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=10.42.0.121 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:19 memory:b3400000-b3407fff
```

**Efforts made**

Tried reinstalling network-manager

Tried this solution from another post

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo ifconfig enp1s0f1 down
sudo ifconfig enp1s0f1 up
sudo service network-manager start
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that the ethernet interface has no IP address. Maybe the failure is related to DHCP, why don't you try using a static IP and see what happen?

Comment: I was about to follow your suggestion and was editing my connection, when I noticed that my connection was trying to use the interface that was provided by the external port. I just changed that to my ethernet interface and it started working. There was no fault with the interface, it was just a problem with how my connection was set up. Thank you so much for the reply. May I go ahead and delete the post as it is not particularly related to networking?